# MongoDb Delete+Insert transaction

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using MongoDb with PHP with custom adapter and have this following code:

```php
$this->adapter->delete($message["id"]);
$this->adapter->insert($message);
```

How can I make this a transaction?

I cannot use update because I have dot in keys which shows error but insert does not raise any exception.

Comment: May be try replacing dot with unicode notation \uffoe
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0e/index.htm

Comment: Do the dots convert back properly when I fetch the document from Db?

Comment: I had similar problem before as I needed version number as key, I replaced it with _ before, using encoder/decoder cause more inconvenience.

Comment: the problem is the stored key with dot is an URL so the escape characters are very limited.... Anyway I am not sure why mongo has not raised exception on insertion

Comment: its a bit late but you can find a tutorial here for php mongodb crud: http://programmerblog.net/php-mongodb-tutorial/